# what curl version is php windows binary running

Tags: php, windows, curl

How can I find out what curl version a specific Windows binary is running without installing it onto a working server?

For example PHP 5.3.5 has curl 7.19.10 on Ubuntu, how can I confirm that the same curl version will be bundled with the Windows binaries for PHP 5.3.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-version.php

```
curl_version();
```

returns

```
Array
(
    [version_number] => 464135
    [age] => 3
    [features] => 2749
    [ssl_version_number] => 0
    [version] => 7.21.7
    [host] => i386-pc-win32
    [ssl_version] => OpenSSL/1.0.0e
    [libz_version] => 1.2.5
    [protocols] => Array
        (
            [0] => dict
            [1] => file
            [2] => ftp
            [3] => ftps
            [4] => gopher
            [5] => http
            [6] => https
            [7] => imap
            [8] => imaps
            [9] => ldap
            [10] => pop3
            [11] => pop3s
            [12] => rtsp
            [13] => scp
            [14] => sftp
            [15] => smtp
            [16] => smtps
            [17] => telnet
            [18] => tftp
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is part of the information printed using `phpinfo()`.  Just make a page with `<?php echo phpinfo();` and you should be set.